# A problem about obtuse-angled triangle

Tags: complex-numbers, triangles

Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ be three distinct complex numbers such that $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ are the vertices of an obtuse-angled triangle with $z_1$ being the obtuse-angled vertex. Then prove that $0$, $\frac{z_1-z_2}{|z_1-z_2|}$, $\frac{z_1-z_3}{|z_1-z_3|}$ are the vertices of an obtuse-angled triangle with $0$ being the obtuse-angled vertex.

I feel that the above statement is true, as it only involves translation and scaling, which in no way change the angles. However, I am difficult to write a formal proof.

Please help me with this solutions!!

Comment: Well, it is different scaling on each point, so the other angles change, but the angle at $z_1$ is equal to the angle at $0,$ and thus the triangle remains obtuse. Just start with the cases where $z_1=0.$

Comment: Will you kindly elaborate@ThomasAndrews. I am not getting the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ represent $(z_1 - z_2)$. 
Let $r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ represent $(z_1 - z_3)$. 
Let $r_3e^{i\theta_3}$ represent $(z_2 - z_3)$.

You are given that $\angle z_2 z_1 z_3$ is obtuse.

This implies that $|\theta_1 - \theta_2| > \pi/2$.

Here, it is presumed that the difference $|\theta_1 - \theta_2|$ is measured so as to be $< \pi$, since this difference represents one of the angles in a triangle.

$\displaystyle \frac{z_1 - z_2}{|z_1 - z_2|} = e^{i\theta_1}.$ 
$\displaystyle \frac{z_1 - z_3}{|z_1 - z_3|} = e^{i\theta_2}.$

Then the angle formed by the points $e^{i\theta_1}, (0,0)$ and $e^{i\theta_2}$ will be $|\theta_1 - \theta_2|$ which has been given as $> \pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @user2661923. However, obtuse means 120 degree.

Comment: @pmun I disagree.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle#Types_of_angles).

Comment: I agree@user2661923